# Umlaute im Fraktursatz

Tags: blackletter, umlaut

Setzt man im Fraktursatz Umlaute auf Großbuchstaben, oder umschreibt man diese mit *Ae* o.ä.? Ich habe bei der Verwendung der *yfonts* in LaTeX festgestellt, dass diese fehlen. Wie ist hier die typographische Regel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Umlaute werden im Fraktursatz in der Regel mit nachgestelltem e wiedergegeben, wenn es sich bei dem Umlaut um **Großbuchstaben** (Majuskeln) handelt:

> Aepfel, Oeſe, Uebung

[image: Fraktur umlauts]

Umlaute als **Kleinbuchstaben** werden, je nach Schrift, durch ein Trema (¨) oder durch ein übergestelltes kleines e gekennzeichnet.

[image: Fraktur umlauts klein]

Historischer Nachsatz:

Im Mittelalter wurde ein langer Umlaut durch die Ligatur (Æ), ein kurzer Umlaut mit Trema (Ä) oder übergestelltem e (Aͤ ) geschrieben. Mit Aufkommen des Buchdrucks wurden Trema und übergestelltes e bei den Großbuchstaben unüblich, weil die Schriftkegel (der rechteckige Block, der den einzelnen Buchstaben trägt) die Höhe der umlautlosen Großbuchstaben hatten und keinen Platz für Trema oder e boten.

Ältere Drucke aus der Zeit des Barock (als die Großschreibung eingeführt wurde) verzichteten deshalb häufig auf die Umlaute und schrieben an ihrer Stelle die nicht umgelauteten Vokale A, O und U (so liest man bei Harsdöffer von den "Apfeln"). Später wurden als Behelf die Punkte oder das e teilweise in den Kreis des O, zwischen die Aufstriche des U oder neben die Spitze des A gestellt.

Erst Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts wurden die Schriftkegel aufgrund eines Beschlusses der Buchdruckerei- und Schriftgießereibesitzer von 1903 entsprechend vergrößert und die typografischen Notbehelfe verschwanden allmählich.

---

Comment: Danke schön! Ist das irgendwo festgeschrieben oder (nur) typographische Konvention? Übrigens: wie heißt dieser schöne Frakturfont?

Comment: 1. Ich kenne leider kein Regelwerk dazu. 2. Fonts kann man hier testen: http://new.myfonts.com/search/Fraktur/fonts/

Comment: Ich habe auch schon Majuskel mit darübergestelltem, kleine `e` gesehen. Aber das ist wohl mehr eine schriftgestalterische Finesse denn eine anerkannte Variante.

Comment: @Tomalak doch, das ist sehr häufig zu sehen; konnte leider keinen Computerfont entdecken, der dies automatisch beherrscht.

Comment: @splattne Man kann die yfonts in LaTeX benutzen und statt `\"a` einfach `\*a` eingeben - das gibt einem ein a mit einem kleinem e darüber.

Comment: @FUZxxl LaTeX ist wunderbar. Leider steht nicht jeder auf Latex. ;-)

Comment: @splattne Ich habe gerade einen [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3313324&group_id=89513&atid=590377) gepostet, dass diese Form der Umlaute auch für die wunderschöne Schriftart Linux Libertine verfügbar wird.

Comment: Ich hab mal eine [Frage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20206/is-there-an-unicode-code-point-for-umlauts-marked-with-a-small-e-instead-of-a-dia) auf tex.SE gestellt. Die haben mich auf den Codepoint U+0364 hingewiesen, der genau das macht. Leider muss der Font das auch unterstützen: aͤ.

Comment: @Hellenologophilist Das ist weder festgeschrieben noch typografische Konvention, sondern ein der Ökonomie geschuldeter Notbehelf. Siehe meine historische Ergänzung.

Comment: Noch eine Anmerkung zum Trema: ich habe noch in den 60er Jahren *"Striche"* ('') und nicht Pünktchen (¨) gelernt. Das ist vermutlich auf ein Überbleibsel der Sütterlinschrift zurückzuführen, bei der ein übergestelltes 'e' wie zwei (verbundene) Striche aussieht ([siehe Bild](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:S%C3%BCtterlin-E.png)).

Answer (score 3):

Ursprünglich wurden statt der heutigen Großbuchstabenumlaute *Ae, Oe* und *Ue* genutzt. Die heutigen Umlaute kamen erst Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts auf, setzten sich dann aber recht schnell durch – auch in der Fraktur. In Duden von 1926 (Fraktur) wird die alte Schreibung bereits gänzlich für falsch erklärt. Vereinzelt gab es auch Schriften, die die alte Form der Umlaute (mit kleinem e über dem Buchstaben) für die Umlaute der Großbuchstaben nutzten.